# Time based loop and Frame based loop

Tags: c++

Trying to understand the concepts of setting constant speed on game loop. My head hurts. I read the [deWiTTERS page](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/), but I can't see the why/how...when I get it...it slips.

```
while(true)
{
      player->update() ;
      player->draw() ;
}
```

This will run as fast as possible depending on how fast a processor is...I get that.

To run at the same speed on all computers, the logic is what I don't get. If I am trying to run at 60fps, then it means for every 16ms the objects move by a frame, yeah? What I don't get is how the `update()` or `draw()` may be too slow.

deWiTTERS example (I used 60):

```
const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;

DWORD next_game_tick = GetTickCount();
// GetTickCount() returns the current number of milliseconds
// that have elapsed since the system was started

int sleep_time = 0;

bool game_is_running = true;

while( game_is_running ) {
    update_game();
    display_game();

    next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
    sleep_time = next_game_tick - GetTickCount();
    if( sleep_time >= 0 ) {
        Sleep( sleep_time );
    }
    else {
        // Shit, we are running behind!
    }
}
```

I don't understand why he gets the current time before the loop starts. And when he increments by `SKIP_TICKS` I understand he increments to the next 16ms interval. But I don't understand this part as well:

```
sleep_time = nextgametick  - GetTickCount()
```

What does `Sleep(sleep_time)` mean? The processor leaves the loop and does something else? How does it achieve running 60fps?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the GetTickCount() is supposed to return between 10-16ms or so yeah? But instead I am seeing stuff like 324505599 as the result...What does "The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. " mean then?

Comment: GetTickCount: The return value is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started. So next_game_tick will have a value of ~324505599 at beginning of the while. The code next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS adds 16 ms to the already existing value (324505615). sleep_time = next_game_tick - GetTickCount() will make sleep_time have the difference between the time for last frame and new frame. If update_game and display_games take more than 16 ms then the value is < 0. if not then sleep.

Comment: Thank you freerider :) Makes more sense now :D
I couldn't so clear an explanation as you guys did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where the update_game() and display_game() functions complete in less time than a single frame interval at 60FPs, the loop tries to ensure that the next frame is not processed until that interval is up, by sleeping (blocking the thread) off the excess frame time.  Seems like it is trying to ensure that the frame rate is capped to 60FPS, and no higher.

The processor does not 'leave the loop' but rather the thread in which your loop is running is blocked (prevented from continuing execution of your code) until the sleep time is up.  Then it continues onto the next frame.  In a multi-threaded game engine, sleeping the thread of the main game loop like this gives the CPU time to execute code in other threads, which may be managing physics, AI, audio mixing etc, depending on set up.

Why is GetTickCount() called before the loop starts?
We know from the comment in your code that GetTickCount() returns the milliseconds since system boot.

So lets say that the system has been running for 30 seconds (30,000ms) when you start your program,
and let's say that we *didn't* call GetTickCount() before entering the loop,
but instead initialized next_game_tick to 0.

We do the update and draw calls (as an example, they take 6ms) and then:

```
next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;  // next_game_tick is now 16
sleep_time = next_game_tick - GetTickCount();   

// GetTickCount() returns 30000!
// So sleep_time is now 16 - 30000 = -29984 !!!
```

Since we (sensibly) only sleep when sleep_time is positive,
the game loop would run as fast as possible (potentially faster than 60FPS),
which is not what you want.

Comment: But if both functions complete in less than 16ms, it might not go to sleep  because the if(sleepTime>0) might not be true..?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your follow up question, so lets take the first frame as an example, and assume that next_game_tick begins at 0.  Now, let's say that update & display are done in 6ms.  next_game_tick is then incremented to 16.  Now sleep_time is 16 - GetTickCount() = 16 - 6 = 10.  So we have 10 milliseconds to sleep off, before we move to the next frame.

Comment: By the way the return value of GetTickCount() is explained in a comment in your code ;-) '...milliseconds since the system was started', i.e. the time passed since your machine was booted.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, you and the guys on this forum help me..StackOverflow rules :P